# Vue Router, Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to redirect the page but I get an error. I think my definitions are correct, why am I getting this error?

Thank you for your help in advance, thankfully you are there.

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router);

import Homepage from './screens/Homepage';
import Journey from './screens/Journey';

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Homepage
    },
    {
      path: '/journey',
      component: Journey
    }
  ]
});

export default router;
```

main.js

```
import Router from './router';
new Vue({
  store: Store,
  router: Router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

my Push..

```
this.$router.push('/journey');
```

Comment: In which file do you write `this.$router.push('/journey')`, is it in a component?

Comment: Yes, it is written in a component in the Homepage. @ShayaUlman

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Now fixed. Problem is "setTimeout". I'm remove setTimeOut, now working.. Thanks for help Shaya...

Answer (score 0):

I think the `this` keyword is undefined at the place where you've written `this.$router.push('/journey');`. So to avoid this at the top of the block scope you can assign `this` keyword to a variable and then use that variable instead of `this`.

```
// Declare this at the top or first line of the function or block scope
let self = this 
.
.
.
.
self.$router.push('/journey');
```